# Ошибки при загрузке Hackintosh с загрузочной флешки

Tags: macos, boot

Я загружал образы Mojave и High Sierra, оба не хотели устанавливаться. Скачивал образ системы в .rdr формате сразу с Clover'ом и через R-DriveImage пилил, как нужно, без ошибок.

Настроил биос и пробовал запустить: на Mojave были ошибки такого рода (каждый раз новая):

```
Error loading kernel cache

Error!!! load prelinked kernel with status (0x...)

allocating 0x11c00 pages at 0x0000000009167000 alloc type 2

attempting system restart... Mach reboot
```

*Бывало, что просто повисла с минуту, появлялись артефакты на экране и знак запрета.*
Всплывали так же в логе какие-то ошибки про ACPI, как вы уже поняли я много тыкал наугад в Config'ах.

В High Sierra уже даже появилось "яблочко" на нескольких конфигах (uefi config и ещё какой-то), но при достижении прогресс баром ~80% появлялся единый знак запрета (фотографии прилагаются), остальные конфиги, которые я пробовал выдавали ошибки, которые я указал выше для Manjaro.
Если Вы хоть что-нибудь знаете по поводу одной из этих ошибок, я буду только рад Вашей помощи.

---

- Intel Pentium G5400
- Nvidia GeForce GT1030
- MSI H110M
- Kingston DDR4 8GB
- SSD + HDD = 1250GB

---

[image: Фриз, после которого появляется то, что на втором фото]
[image: Артефакты и знак запрета]
[image: Загрузка до 80%]
[[image: Проблемы с ещё не установленной системой[4]]

Comment: Купите нормальный человеческий Macintosh. Не надо натягивать на глобус.

Comment: Вы меня, конечно, извините, но у меня нет лишних $10,000 на такое удовольствие. Я считаю эту цену просто неприемлемой.
Было бы неплохо опробовать MacOS на своём ПК перед, предположим, покупкой Macbook

Comment: Они не самые дорогие из премиум класса. А ваш вопрос вам фактически ответ дал — не нужен вам ни hackintosh, ни человеческий Mac.