# Установка hackintosh на ПК

Tags: mac, ос

Железо достаточно новое i5-9400, rtx3060, 40gb ОЗУ.

Пытаюсь установить Monterey, плюс использую clover. Образ использую dmg и программу transmac.

При перезапуске автоматически открывается окно clover, выбираю образ мака. Начинает грузиться, но выдаёт ошибку (как на фото).

Включаю -V в clover для отображения ошибки, но появляются артефакты, и та же ошибка.

Также на stackOverflow есть похожий вопрос с точно такими же скринами как у меня, без ответов. [тот самый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989665/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-hackintosh-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Запрещающий знак в виде круга с косой чертой означает, что загрузочный диск содержит операционную систему, но на данном компьютере использовать данную версию или сборку macOS невозможно. Возможно в твоем случае проблема именно в том что отсутствует чип Neural Engine. Если вкратце, то проблема с внутрянкой, кстати не факт что именно с Neural Engine (у меня точно такая же проблема была, но плюнул и поставил сиеру. С ней все ок).